# Debian Lenny Bastille Alternative

Tags: debian-lenny

as the Debian Lenny (5.0) repository version of Bastille does not support version 5.0, I was wondering if there is an alternative.

Kind regards, Benjamin.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [AppArmor](https://apparmor.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) or [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page).